# Loop to get all probabilities of combining words

Tags: c#, combinatorics

I have text that contains spaces.
I want all the possibilities. For example, merge a space and leave  another.
For example, this is the first possibility:
the first word, then a space, the second word, then a space, then the third word.
The second possibility:
the first word, then without a space, then the second word, then a space, then the third word.
The third possibility:
the first word, then a space, then the second word, then without a space, then the third word ... etc..
I want to do this, but in a loop, especially if the number of words is more than five, six, or more.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string test = "aaa bbb ccc";
        var ch = test.Split(' ');
        var t1 = ch[0] + " " + ch[1] + " " + ch[2];
        var t2 = ch[0] + "" + ch[1] + " " + ch[2];
        var t3 = ch[0] + " " + ch[1] + "" + ch[2];
        var t4 = ch[0] + "" + ch[1] + "" + ch[2];

        Console.WriteLine(t1);
        Console.WriteLine(t2);
        Console.WriteLine(t3);
        Console.WriteLine(t4);

        string test2 = "aaa bbb ccc ddd";
        var ch2 = test2.Split(' ');
        var z1 = ch2[0] + " " + ch2[1] + " " + ch2[2] + " " + ch2[3];
        var z2 = ch2[0] + "" + ch2[1] + " " + ch2[2] + " " + ch2[3];
        var z3 = ch2[0] + " " + ch2[1] + "" + ch2[2] + " " + ch2[3];
        var z4 = ch2[0] + " " + ch2[1] + " " + ch2[2] + "" + ch2[3];
        var z5 = ch2[0] + "" + ch2[1] + "" + ch2[2] + " " + ch2[3];
        var z6 = ch2[0] + " " + ch2[1] + "" + ch2[2] + "" + ch2[3];
        var z7 = ch2[0] + "" + ch2[1] + "" + ch2[2] + "" + ch2[3];

        Console.WriteLine(z1);
        Console.WriteLine(z2);
        Console.WriteLine(z3);
        Console.WriteLine(z4);
        Console.WriteLine(z5);
        Console.WriteLine(z6);
        Console.WriteLine(z7);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Off topic, but just missed a combination somewhere, the variables should go from `z1` to `z8` but you only have 7.

Comment: Seems like a "do my homework for me" question

Comment: I'm sorry, sir. I'm a beginner. I'm going to delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if we have `n` words we have `n - 1` possible spaces. Let `0` be absence of space, when `1` be a presence of space:

```
[0, 0, 0] => Word1Word2Word3Word4
[0, 0, 1] => Word1Word2Word3 Word4
[0, 1, 0] => Word1Word2 Word3Word4
[0, 1, 1] => Word1Word2 Word3 Word4
...
[1, 1, 1] => Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4
```

So far so good we should enumerate all `2 ^ (n - 1)` binary masks:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

...

private static IEnumerable<string> Solution(params string[] words) {
  return Enumerable
    .Range(0, 1 << (words.Length - 1))
    .Select(mask => {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(words[0]);

       for (int i = 0; i < words.Length - 1; ++i) {
         if ((mask & (1 << i)) != 0)
           sb.Append(' ');

         sb.Append(words[i + 1]);
       }
  
       return sb.ToString();
    });
}
```

Demo ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bDE37X)):

```
var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Solution("A", "B", "C", "D"));
        
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output:

```
ABCD
A BCD
AB CD
A B CD
ABC D
A BC D
AB C D
A B C D
```